# How can I use a variable from another script in c# in unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visualizer, mindwave

I want to make a visualizer that shows the meditation value from the Neurosky mindwave. It is a project for my university class (in Communication Design), so I'm quite new to code. I want to work with the VFX Graph for the visualization and I made a prototype where you can change the Size as a parameter. Now I want to set the meditation value as the parameter, so it changes the size accordingly. For the Mindwave part I am using this code:[https://github.com/DaCookie/mindwave-unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Fq5.jpg)

My problem is that I can't seem to access to the value from one script to the other. And I'm also not sure if I found the correct meditation value that I can use.

I tried to access to the other script with GetComponent, but it's not working. 
Can you help me with that? Or has someone worked with the Mindwave before and can show me how to use the meditation value?

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Fq5.jpg)

[The Code with the meditation value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbUNy.jpg)